# Dynamically create hierachical tableview from file structure

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a directory structure of directories and files that I want to render as a tableview in an iphone app.  I'd rather have this generated dynamically rather than have to maintain a XML PLIST or whatever.  i.e. replicate the Explorer functionality in windows where a user can traverse the structure and then select bundled image files for viewing.

Is there any way to do this?  Any advice would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specifically are you having trouble with?

You use `NSFileManager` to access directory (listings) and files.

You use `UITableView` to display tables.

Your view controller should use `NSFileManager` to parse a given directory and display the results in a `UITableView`.